# Retrieve selected menu item text from onItemClick - Android?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, listitem

I understand this question has been asked several times. You would think at least one of the solutions would have helped me but no such luck.

I have the following code that populates a list view correctly ([also found here](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php#activity)):

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  

    // Find the ListView resource.   
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );  

    // Create and populate a List of planet names.  
    String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",  
                                      "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};    
    ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();  
    planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );  

    // Create ArrayAdapter using the planet list.  
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, planetList);  


    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );        
  }
```

However, unsuccessful at getting the text of the item selected.

For example, the user selects "Mars", what function returns the text "Mars" in the function:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

// Retrieve selected text here?
}
```

Comment: have u tried this `String strselected_value=planets[pos];` inside onItemClick

Comment: @k: planets cannot be resolved at this level

Comment: then declare  `ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();`  at class level means out side  onCreate method of Activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

   String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos); // This is the selected text.
}
```

Comment: thanks! I can accept answer in 5 minutes. FYI - need to return string: String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos). **toString();**

Comment: cause you define the adapter as ArrayAdapter<String>, I don't think you need to call toString() once again. If compiler gives some warning, just cast it as: (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);